# Google Apps Script - Cannot parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

Google script running inside a Google Sheet.

Trying a very simple fetch from an API, but cannot get the response parameters as I cannot get it to parse.

Here's my code:

```js
function neutrinoapilookup() {
    var lookupUrl = "https://neutrinoapi.net/phone-validate?user-id=123456789justtesting123@gmail.com&api-key=k00h86sr9ayZgcs2x77Zd5FUCHLlkF86hN23mAHQOG4R4Pq2&number=1567687436"
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(lookupUrl, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(data.valid);
}
```

Here's the error:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function parse in object
> [object Object]. (line 5, file "neutrinoapi") [0.17 seconds total
> runtime]

The response and the json line are running fine.
response.getContentText() results in

> {"valid":true,"country":"XXXX","country-code":"XX","prefix-network":"XXXX","international-number":"XXXXXX","location":"XXXX","local-number":"XXXXX","type":"mobile","currency-code":"XXX","international-calling-code":"XXX","is-mobile":true,"country-code3":"XXX"}

This is correct response as per the [documentation here](https://www.neutrinoapi.com/api/phone-validate/).

I thought maybe V8 runtime would solve it, but no. When using V8 I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class'
> at unknown function

I'm sure it's a coding101 issue.

Comment: which line causes the error? can you paste what your `response.getContext()` returns please? I'm also assuming that you have a proper user id and api key in your url, don't you?

Comment: This line generates the error: var data = JSON.parse(json). I've edited my question to address the other issues you mention.

Comment: can you share exactly what `response.getContentText()` returns? feel free to replace any sensitive data. it's important to see the format, it might not be valid json.

Comment: {"valid":true,"country":"XXXX","country-code":"XX","prefix-network":"XXXX","international-number":"XXXXXX","location":"XXXX","local-number":"XXXXX","type":"mobile","currency-code":"XXX","international-calling-code":"XXX","is-mobile":true,"country-code3":"XXX"}

Comment: Something is missing from the data you are providing. I replaced `response.getContext()` with your string [and it works](https://imgur.com/a/VndHSiJ). Try to do what I did, but put your actual data in your `json` variable.

Comment: Side note: You can [edit] your question and add relevant details there - for example, the line causing the error, and the JSON response - instead of providing them in comments. These details are directly relevant to the question. They can tend to become lost in comments (and are harder to format & harder to read).

Comment: Thanks. I used getContext and got roughly the same error: TypeError: Cannot find function getContext in object

Comment: Likely your 'fetch()' is returning something weird then. But you're going to have to make an effort and give us a reproducible example

Comment: I've updated the question with a reproducible code.

Comment: Everything is working fine ... you really get a json as follows : `{"valid":false,"country":"United States","country-code":"US",___________,"international-calling-code":"1","is-mobile":false,"country-code3":"USA"}`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. If the variable `response` contains an object you can try to call its properties directly:

```
function neutrinoapilookup() {
    var lookupUrl = "https://neutrinoapi.net/phone-validate?user-id=YOUR_USER_ID&api-key=YOUR_API_KEY&number=6495552048"        
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(lookupUrl, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    // var json = response.getContentText(); // <--- doesn't need?
    // var data = JSON.parse(json);          // <--- doesn't need?
    console.log(response.valid);
}
```

If `responce` is a string it unlikely has the method `getContentText()`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it. Not working. response.valid return "undefined".

Comment: Well. I just tried example from your updated question and your snippet works just fine for me. It gets me the valid json and "false" in my console. https://i.imgur.com/XrZPJF8.png https://i.imgur.com/PAkiouU.png

Comment: I can't see the console log in which it states "false", but I'm sure you're right. So it's something with my machine. How do you recommend I solve it? PS - did you try from a Google Apps Script engine?

Comment: I've added one more screenshot to my comment, with "false". I've ran the script from spreadsheet Script Editor (V8). Sorry, I have no idea how it can be solved. I hope someone has a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. As you all mentioned, it's indeed working after restarting the script manager.